# Shortened link navigation

Tags: html

I'm new to web development and tried searching answers to this, but only found responses of how to shorten urls to bit.ly etc. I appreciate any help! My site is still in development, so the url will change and I'm only using the truncated link to navigate between sites ie. home.html. I have folders, so added the folder name, ie. blog/name.html. to navigate into it correctly. But how do I navigate out of the folder? The link from blog/name.html to home.html didn't find the page because it's outside of the folder. Thanks.

Comment: Either `/home.html` or `../home.html` (but the former will always work). It's the same as navigating directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/name.html` if the file is within the same folder

Use `../folder/name.html` if the file is outside folder. The two dots refer to going back to root directory.